# Creating Directory Loops by Manipulating ext4

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

For academic purposes I am messing with some file systems.
One of my goals is to create a directory loop inside each of the File Systems.
Currently I am stuck with ext4 which for some reason won't work as the others.

I created two folders, 'top' and 'bottom' and try to manipulate the on-disk structure of ext4 to create some kind of hard-link from bottom back to top, resulting in an indefinite loop.

The problem is, when I browse the filesystem with `ls`, it either does not show both folders (although I only manipulated the bottom one) or it shows top, but inside top the directory listing is broken as follows:

```
ls: Access to bottom not possible: I/O Error (freely translated from german)
total 2
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 1024 Nov 14 15:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 1024 Nov 14 15:48 ..
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? bottom
```

The steps I took so far are:

1. Locate the inode table entry for inode of top (entry 12), see that it points to block 3510
2. Next inode table entry is for bottom (entry 13), see that it points to block 3511
3. Go to block 3510, let . and .. untouched but change the inode number of bottom to 12
4. Try accessing the directory with `ls` -> Error
5. Go to block 3511, change . to inode 12, .. to inode 2 (for root directory)
6. Try accessing the directory with `ls` -> Error
7. Change inode entry 13 in inode table and let it point to block 3510
8. Same error as usual

I realise that inodes and the extent trees inside an inode entry have hashsums but my understanding is that steps 1 to 3 should not make any of these hash values invalid.
My understanding of the internal working of `ls` is probably to low to find out what I am doing wrong here.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong or is there a better approach to achieve what I am trying to do? Help is very much appreciated as I need that loop for my bachelor's thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured out what the problem was.

Looking around in the syslog I found that whenever browsing the directory I would get the following message:

`ext4_lookup:1376: inode #12: comm ls: 'bottom' linked to parent dir`

After searching the internet for a while and asking ext4 developers on IRC I finally found [this](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/stable-queue.git/diff/queue-3.4/ext4-disallow-hard-linked-directory-in-ext4_lookup.patch?id=fc126d9ef33b426f811ab822d1ab751d3d172e71) patch committed to the ext4 filesystem code that targets exactly what I tried to do.
Nice patch, but here's what you can do to get a directory loop anyhow:

```
"/"
 |--"top_1"
 |   \--"bottom_1" --> "top_2"
 | 
 \--"top_2"
     \--"bottom_2" --> "top_1"
```